# Numerical integration error

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

When I run the following script below, I get the error `Too many input arguments` (I have figured out that this specifically happens when calculating `intNH(5,2)` in the second `for` loop). Basically what is happening is that `fun2` for `i=5` equals `0` (because the relevant `G` element is `0`) and MATLAB cannot numerically integrate a function equal to zero (or that's how I've interpreted this).

Does anyone have any pointers about how I can overcome this? I have tried some `if` statements saying that if the function is equal to `0` then `intNH = 0`, else numerically integrate as normal, but more errors keep happening when I try this!

```
%%Calculation of dH/dt for mode m=1 for the entire sphere, NH and SH
clear all
%%Radius of photosphere
R = 6.957*(10^5); %In km

%%Call in spherical harmonic coefficients, change the 535 figure as more
%%data is added to the spreadsheets
G(:,1) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'C3:C535');
G(:,2) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'E3:E535');
G(:,3) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'H3:H535');
G(:,4) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'L3:L535');
G(:,5) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'Q3:Q535');
G(:,6) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'W3:W535');
G(:,7) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'AD3:AD535');
G(:,8) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'AL3:AL535');
G(:,9) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'AU3:AU535');

%%Set function v which always remains the same
nhztoradperday = 2*pi*86400*(10^(-9));
a = 460.7*nhztoradperday;
b = -62.69*nhztoradperday;
c = -67.13*nhztoradperday;

syms t %t short for theta here
V = a + (b*cos(t)^2) + (c*cos(t)^4);

zero = @(t) 0*t;

%%Set B and A functions within separate matrices

for i = 1:length(G)

    B(i,1) = G(i,1)*cos(t);

    B(i,2) = 0.5*G(i,2)*(3*(cos(t)^2)-1);

    B(i,3) = 0.5*G(i,3)*(5*(cos(t)^3)-3*cos(t));

    B(i,4) = 1/8*G(i,4)*(35*(cos(t)^4)-30*(cos(t)^2)+3);

    B(i,5) = 1/8*G(i,5)*(63*(cos(t)^5)-70*(cos(t)^3)+15*cos(t));

    B(i,6) = 1/16*G(i,6)*(231*(cos(t)^6)-315*(cos(t)^4)+105*(cos(t)^2)-5);

    B(i,7) = 1/16*G(i,7)*(429*(cos(t)^7)-693*(cos(t)^5)+315*(cos(t)^3)-35*cos(t));

    B(i,8) = 1/128*G(i,8)*(6435*(cos(t)^8)-12012*(cos(t)^6)+6930*(cos(t)^4)-1260*(cos(t)^2)+35);

    B(i,9) = 1/128*G(i,9)*(12155*(cos(t)^9)-25740*(cos(t)^7)+18018*(cos(t)^5)-4620*(cos(t)^3)+315*cos(t));


    A(i,1) = 0.5*R*G(i,1)*sin(t);

    A(i,2) = 0.5*R*G(i,2)*csc(t)*(cos(t)-(cos(t)^3));

    A(i,3) = 0.5*R*G(i,3)*csc(t)*(1.5*(cos(t)^2)-1.25*(cos(t)^4)-0.25);

    A(i,4) = 1/8*R*G(i,4)*csc(t)*(-7*(cos(t)^5)+10*(cos(t)^3)-3*cos(t));

    A(i,5) = 1/8*R*G(i,5)*csc(t)*(-21/2*(cos(t)^6)+35/2*(cos(t)^4)-15/2*(cos(t)^2)+0.5);

    A(i,6) = 1/16*R*G(i,6)*csc(t)*(-33*(cos(t)^7)+63*(cos(t)^5)-35*(cos(t)^3)+5*cos(t));

    A(i,7) = 1/16*R*G(i,7)*csc(t)*(-429/8*(cos(t)^8)+231/2*(cos(t)^6)-315/4*(cos(t)^4)+35/2*(cos(t)^2)-5/8);

    A(i,8) = 1/128*R*G(i,8)*csc(t)*(-715*(cos(t)^9)+1716*(cos(t)^7)-1386*(cos(t)^5)+420*(cos(t)^3)-35*cos(t));

    A(i,9) = 1/128*R*G(i,9)*csc(t)*(-2431/2*(cos(t)^10)+6435/2*(cos(t)^8)-3003*(cos(t)^6)+1155*(cos(t)^4)-315/2*(cos(t)^2)+7/2);

end
    %Turn vector V from a sym to a function and compute V at equator
    Vfunc = matlabFunction(V);
    Veq = Vfunc(0);

    for i=1:length(G)

        fun(1) = 0; fun(2) = 0; fun(3) = 0; fun(4) = 0; fun(5) = 0; fun(6) = 0; 
        fun(7) = 0; fun(8) = 0; fun(9) = 0;

        %Create functions for integration
        fun(1) = matlabFunction(B(i,1).*A(i,1).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(2) = matlabFunction(B(i,2).*A(i,2).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(3) = matlabFunction(B(i,3).*A(i,3).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(4) = matlabFunction(B(i,4).*A(i,4).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(5) = matlabFunction(B(i,5).*A(i,5).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(6) = matlabFunction(B(i,6).*A(i,6).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(7) = matlabFunction(B(i,7).*A(i,7).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(8) = matlabFunction(B(i,8).*A(i,8).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));
        fun(9) = matlabFunction(B(i,9).*A(i,9).*(V-Veq).*sin(t));

        %Compute numerical integral for each order and store values

        %Northern Hemisphere
        intNH(i,1) = integral(fun1,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,2) = integral(fun2,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,3) = integral(fun3,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,4) = integral(fun4,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,5) = integral(fun5,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,6) = integral(fun6,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,7) = integral(fun7,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,8) = integral(fun8,0,pi/2);
        intNH(i,9) = integral(fun9,0,pi/2);   

        %Southern Hemisphere
        intSH(i,1) = int(fun1,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,2) = int(fun2,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,3) = int(fun3,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,4) = int(fun4,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,5) = int(fun5,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,6) = int(fun6,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,7) = int(fun7,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,8) = int(fun8,t,pi/2,pi);
        intSH(i,9) = int(fun9,t,pi/2,pi);

        %Whole Sun
        intSun(i,1) = int(fun1,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,2) = int(fun2,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,3) = int(fun3,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,4) = int(fun4,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,5) = int(fun5,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,6) = int(fun6,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,7) = int(fun7,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,8) = int(fun8,t,0,pi);
        intSun(i,9) = int(fun9,t,0,pi);

        %Sum over all orders to get a value for dH/dt
        NH(i) = sum(dintNH(i,:));
        SH(i) = sum(intSH(i,:));
        Sun(i) = sum(intSun(i,:));

    end

x = linspace(1643,2175,533);

figure(1)
plot(x,NH)
xlabel('Carrington Rotation')
ylabel('Magnetic helicity transport')
title('Northern Hemisphere magnetic helicity transport via twisting motions on the boundary vs Carrington Rotations')

figure(2)
plot(x,SH)
xlabel('Carrington Rotation')
ylabel('Magnetic helicity transport')
title('Southern Hemisphere magnetic helicity transport via twisting motions on the boundary vs Carrington Rotations')

figure(3)
plot(x,Sun)
xlabel('Carrington Rotation')
ylabel('Magnetic helicity transport')
title('Whole sun magnetic helicity transport via twisting motions on the boundary vs Carrington Rotations')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code. All this magic you're doing with syms and setting function-valued arrays manually is entirely unnecessary, and it's hard to tell where the exact problem is coming from (if you put this code into a function, at least we'd know the line where the error comes from...).

You should just use anonymous functions, just like the one called `zero` in your code. All you have are analytically defined functions and numbers. You can only store function (handles) in `cell` objects, though, not in arrays. So `fun{k}` and friends should be assigned for this. But if you rewrite your code to work with numerical values (which is actually optimal for MATLAB too), you'll end up a happier person.

For instance, your first loop is equivalent to this:

```
B{1} = @(t)  G(:,1)*cos(t);

B{2} = @(t)  0.5*G(:,2)*(3*(cos(t)^2)-1);

B{3} = @(t)  0.5*G(:,3)*(5*(cos(t)^3)-3*cos(t));

B{4} = @(t)  1/8*G(:,4)*(35*(cos(t)^4)-30*(cos(t)^2)+3);

B{5} = @(t)  1/8*G(:,5)*(63*(cos(t)^5)-70*(cos(t)^3)+15*cos(t));

B{6} = @(t)  1/16*G(:,6)*(231*(cos(t)^6)-315*(cos(t)^4)+105*(cos(t)^2)-5);

B{7} = @(t)  1/16*G(:,7)*(429*(cos(t)^7)-693*(cos(t)^5)+315*(cos(t)^3)-35*cos(t));

B{8} = @(t)  1/128*G(:,8)*(6435*(cos(t)^8)-12012*(cos(t)^6)+6930*(cos(t)^4)-1260*(cos(t)^2)+35);

B{9} = @(t)  1/128*G(:,9)*(12155*(cos(t)^9)-25740*(cos(t)^7)+18018*(cos(t)^5)-4620*(cos(t)^3)+315*cos(t));


A{1} = @(t)  0.5*R*G(:,1)*sin(t);

A{2} = @(t)  0.5*R*G(:,2)*csc(t)*(cos(t)-(cos(t)^3));

A{3} = @(t)  0.5*R*G(:,3)*csc(t)*(1.5*(cos(t)^2)-1.25*(cos(t)^4)-0.25);

A{4} = @(t)  1/8*R*G(:,4)*csc(t)*(-7*(cos(t)^5)+10*(cos(t)^3)-3*cos(t));

A{5} = @(t)  1/8*R*G(:,5)*csc(t)*(-21/2*(cos(t)^6)+35/2*(cos(t)^4)-15/2*(cos(t)^2)+0.5);

A{6} = @(t)  1/16*R*G(:,6)*csc(t)*(-33*(cos(t)^7)+63*(cos(t)^5)-35*(cos(t)^3)+5*cos(t));

A{7} = @(t)  1/16*R*G(:,7)*csc(t)*(-429/8*(cos(t)^8)+231/2*(cos(t)^6)-315/4*(cos(t)^4)+35/2*(cos(t)^2)-5/8);

A{8} = @(t)  1/128*R*G(:,8)*csc(t)*(-715*(cos(t)^9)+1716*(cos(t)^7)-1386*(cos(t)^5)+420*(cos(t)^3)-35*cos(t));

A{9} = @(t)  1/128*R*G(:,9)*csc(t)*(-2431/2*(cos(t)^10)+6435/2*(cos(t)^8)-3003*(cos(t)^6)+1155*(cos(t)^4)-315/2*(cos(t)^2)+7/2);
```

These are all cells containing array-valued function handles. Each of these functions gets a single value `t` and outputs an array of length `length(G)`.

Later, you can do

```
V = @(t) a + (b*cos(t)^2) + (c*cos(t)^4);
Veq = V(0);
% todo: pre-allocate fun
intNH = zeros(length(G),9);
for k=1:9
   fun{k} = @(t) B{k}(t).*A{k}(t).*(V(t)-Veq).*sin(t);
   intNH(:,k) = integral(fun{k},0,pi/2,'arrayvalued',true);
end
```

and so on.

Comment: Oh, I should probably mention the fun(number) parts aren't supposed to be there, I only started to assign them to arrays when I was playing around with the code!!

Comment: @RThompson indeed. If you rewrite it in the way I did, it's clear that you don't need to store those last set of functions, since you can just define-integrate-store in the loop, each function after the next. Note that you *could* define matrix-valued anonymous functions for `A` and `B`, and then you could avoid the loop over `k` entirely.

Comment: Can the functions be stored in a cell, say B{i,2}? The only reason I ask is so that my supervisor or myself can check the functions in the future (or we may need them for something else)

Comment: Of course, but cells are slow, and I suggest avoiding them as much as possible. In the current implementation, `tmpvar=B{2}(t); tmpvar=tmpvar(i);` is equivalent to `tmpvar=B{i,2}` in the other scenario. Is this clear?

Comment: I rewrote it the way you suggested and it sped up run time immensely, thank you so much! I will use cell assignment more often in the future!!!

Comment: No, use arrays in the future;) Do try using full matrix-valued arrays. I mean something like `B=@(t) [G(:,1)*cos(t), 0.5*G(:,2)*(3*(cos(t)^2)-1), ...]` for all 9 elements; the result will be a matrix-valued function handle: `B(2)` will be a matrix of size `[length(G),9]`. Then you just say `intNH = integral(fun,...,'arrayvalued',true)` and the result will be automagically the same size. This should be fastest:)

Comment: Full matrix-valued arrays is what I actually meant in my mind (I'm a bit terrible when it comes to all of these Matlab terms!). It is so much faster than what I had before it's hard to believe I've been doing it wrong for so long!!

Comment: Hi again! I have tried to use this method for changing a script which is like the one above, but instead concerns functions of two variables rather than one. I keep receiving errors on this and I'm not sure why. If you wouldn't mind to take a look at it for me, it'd be greatly appreciated! Here is the link to the question if you wanted to take a look and thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104305/double-numerical-integration-error