# Double Numerical Integration Error

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

In the script below, in the for loop for calculating the double integrations, I keep receiving an error, and I'm unsure why:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(t,p)-sin(t)*(G(:,1)*cos(p)+H(:,1)*sin(p))


Error in @(t,p)B{k}(t,p).*A{k}(t,p).*(V(t)-Veq).*sin(t)


Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 228)
        Z = FUN(X,Y);  NFE = NFE + 1;

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 9)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral2 (line 106)
    Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
```

This script was formed from another which only had to deal with one variable t, so I'm assuming that I've done something wrong in adapting it to two variable functions.

Thanks!

```
%%Calculation of dH/dt for mode m=1 for the entire sphere, NH and SH
clear all
%%Radius of photosphere
r = 6.957*(10^5); %In km
R = 1/r; %This will come in handy later

%%Call in spherical harmonic coefficients, change the 535 figure as more
%%data is added to the spreadsheets
G(:,1) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'D3:D535');
G(:,2) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'F3:F535');
G(:,3) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'I3:I535');
G(:,4) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'M3:M535');
G(:,5) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'R3:R535');
G(:,6) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'X3:X535');
G(:,7) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'AE3:AE535');
G(:,8) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'AM3:AM535');
G(:,9) = xlsread('G Coefficients.xls', 'AV3:AV535');

H(:,1) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'D3:D535');
H(:,2) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'F3:F535');
H(:,3) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'I3:I535');
H(:,4) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'M3:M535');
H(:,5) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'R3:R535');
H(:,6) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'X3:X535');
H(:,7) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'AE3:AE535');
H(:,8) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'AM3:AM535');
H(:,9) = xlsread('H Coefficients.xls', 'AV3:AV535');

%%Set function v which always remains the same
nhztoradperday = 2*pi*86400*(10^(-9));
a = 460.7*nhztoradperday;
b = -62.69*nhztoradperday;
c = -67.13*nhztoradperday;

B{1} = @(t,p) -sin(t)*(G(:,1)*cos(p) + H(:,1)*sin(p));

B{2} = @(t,p) -3*sin(t)*cos(t)*(G(:,2)*cos(p) + H(:,2)*sin(p));

B{3} = @(t,p) -1.5*(5*(cos(t)^2)-1)*sin(t)*(G(:,3)*cos(p) + H(:,3)*sin(p));

B{4} = @(t,p) -2.5*(7*(cos(t)^3)-3*cos(t))*sin(t)*(G(:,4)*cos(p) + H(:,4)*sin(p));

B{5} = @(t,p) -1.875*sin(t)*(21*(cos(t)^4)-14*(cos(t)^2)+1)*(G(:,5)*cos(p) + H(:,5)*sin(p));

B{6} = @(t,p) -2.625*cos(t)*sin(t)*(33*(cos(t)^4)-30*(cos(t)^2)+5)*(G(:,6)*cos(p) + H(:,6)*sin(p));

B{7} = @(t,p) -0.4375*sin(t)*(429*(cos(t)^6)-495*(cos(t)^4)+135*(cos(t)^2)-5)*(G(:,7)*cos(p) + H(:,7)*sin(p));

B{8} = @(t,p) -0.5625*cos(t)*sin(t)*(715*(cos(t)^6)-1001*(cos(t)^4)+385*(cos(t)^2)-35)*(G(:,8)*cos(p) + H(:,8)*sin(p));



A{1} = @(t,p) 0.5*R*cos(t)*(G(:,1)*cos(p) + H(:,1)*sin(p));

A{2} = @(t,p) 0.5*R*cos(2*t)*(G(:,2)*cos(p) + H(:,2)*sin(p));

A{3} = @(t,p) 0.125*R*cos(t)*(15*(cos(t)^2)-11)*(G(:,3)*cos(p) + H(:,3)*sin(p));

A{4} = @(t,p) 0.125*R*(-3*cos(2*t)+7*(cos(t)^4-3*sin(t)^2*cos(t)^2))*(G(:,4)*cos(p) + H(:,4)*sin(p));

A{5} = @(t,p) 0.0625*R*(21*(cos(t)^5)-(cos(t)^3)*(14+84*(sin(t)^2))+cos(t)*(1+28*(sin(t)^2)))*(G(:,5)*cos(p) + H(:,5)*sin(p));

A{6} = @(t,p) 0.0625*R*(33*(cos(t)^6)-(cos(t)^4)*(165*(sin(t)^2)+30)+90*(sin(t)^2)*(cos(t)^2)+5*cos(2*t))*(G(:,6)*cos(p) + H(:,6)*sin(p));

A{7} = @(t,p) 1/128*R*(429*(cos(t)^7)-(cos(t)^5)*(495+2574*(sin(t)^2))+(cos(t)^3)*(135+1980*(sin(t)^2))-cos(t)*(5+270*(sin(t)^2)))*(G(:,7)*cos(p) + H(:,7)*sin(p));

A{8} = @(t,p) 1/128*R*(715*(cos(t)^8)-1001*(cos(t)^6)+385*(cos(t)^4)-35*(cos(t)^2)+(sin(t)^2)*(-5005*(cos(t)^6)+5005*(cos(t)^4)-1155*(cos(t)^2)+35))*(G(:,8)*cos(p) + H(:,8)*sin(p));

V = @(t) a + (b*cos(t)^2) + (c*cos(t)^4);
Veq = V(0);

intNH = zeros(length(G),9);
intSH = zeros(length(G),9);
intSun = zeros(length(G),9);
for k=1:8
   fun{k} = @(t,p) B{k}(t,p).*A{k}(t,p).*(V(t)-Veq).*sin(t);
   intNH(:,k) = integral2(fun{k},0,pi/2,0,2*pi);
   intSH(:,k) = integral2(fun{k},pi/2,pi,0,2*pi);
   intSun(:,k) = integral2(fun{k},0,pi,0,2*pi);
end

for i=1:length(G)
   NH(i) = sum(intNH(i,:));
   SH(i) = sum(intSH(i,:));
   Sun(i) = sum(intSun(i,:));
end
```

Comment: Don't dump a huge amount of code here and says "it has an error". Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I have edited it to include the error

Comment: The error is quite clear _" 'arrayvalued' is not a recognized parameter. For a list of valid name-value pair arguments, see the documentation for this
function."_ . So `'arrayvalued'` is not an allowed parameter. You need to look at the documentation for the function (for your Matlab version). Type `doc integral2` to get up the documentation.

Comment: The only documentation available for integral2 are error tolerances (which I don't require here) or the method of integration, which I think I also don't require here. However, if I just take the _'array valued'_ out of the code I get more errors

Comment: I have edited the question to incorporate the new error

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you are trying to attempt will probably not work as-is. Considering that I know the history of the question, I know you're trying to integrate an array-valued function. [This worked in 1d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101524/numerical-integration-error), but I'm afraid it won't work in 2d.

If you look at the help of `integral2` as it has already been suggested in comments, you'll see this:

> All input functions must accept arrays as input and operate elementwise. The function `Z = FUN(X,Y)` must accept arrays `X` and `Y` of the same size and return an array of corresponding values.

This means that the output from the `fun` entering `integral2` can't have more dimensions than the input; in other words `integral2` will only integrate scalar functions for you.

After a cursory glance over the options, I don't think the built-in 2d integrators support this. You have two options, and each are inefficient, so you should try both and see which is better for your application.

Option one you already know: loop over each index of your array-valued function, and integrate these scalars using `interp2`. This will be slow because you need a loop over the elements of your array, and `interp2d` has to be called for each.

Option two is to perform the double integral as two single integrals. I mean formally doing

```
integrated_result = integral(@(t)integral(@(p) fun(t,p),p1,p2,'arrayvalued',true),...
                             t1,t2,'arrayvalued',true);
```

to integrate in `p` from `p1` to `p2` and from `t1` to `t2`. This will be slow because for each value of the outer variables you need to call `integral`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a shame the 1d method won't work. I do actually already have a script for this 2d method that does work, but it takes about 15-20 minutes to run. I just hoped this method may speed things up but I guess not!

Comment: @RThompson I suggest checking out the double-`integral` version I showed, unless that's the one you already have implemented.

Comment: The method I already used was your option 1, I will try the double integral version to see if it runs faster!

Comment: @RThompson please let me know how it goes:)